# How to disable TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 in VSFTPD on Debian 10 Buster?

Tags: https, ftp

I'm done with the insecure FTP and serve only FTP over SSL in my VSFTPD on Debian 10 Buster.

---

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/vsftpd.conf) is not clear at all as per my question:

How do I disable the **20 years old [TLSv1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.0)** and also the **13 years old [TLSv1.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.1)** in my VSFTPD on Debian 10 Buster and keep only **[TLSv1.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.2)**?

---

PS: With the new coming up standard - **[TLSv1.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.3)** - it also comes to my mind how to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might look strange as it does not allow any protocol; But it actually does allow TLSv1.2 + TLSv1.3:

Disallow the **the oldest [SSLv2 and SSLv3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#SSL_1.0,_2.0,_and_3.0)** protocols with:

```
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
```

Disallow the **already being deprecated [TLSv1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.0)** protocol with:

```
ssl_tlsv1=NO
```

---

This will **automatically enable** the newer protocol **[TLSv1.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.2)** and even the latest **[TLSv1.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.3)**! (If that is supported by your system.)

Note, that you also need to specify ciphers which are to be used, I use only AES-256 ciphers, so feel free to tune this to your needs:

```
ssl_ciphers=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

---

You might need to verify your setup afterwards. I personally use [High-Tech Bridge](https://www.htbridge.com/ssl/) SSL tester for FTP since you can specify the port there.

---

Example result with the above settings:

[image: High-Tech Bridge example FTP result]